# How do I root my Dell Venue 3830 tablet?

Tags: root-access, dell

I went here:

http://opensource.dell.com/releases/Venue_8_3830_CloverTrail_plus/developer-edition/

and did all this successfully: http://opensource.dell.com/releases/Venue_8_3830_CloverTrail_plus/developer-edition/Dell%20Tablet%20Install%20Instructions.pdf

Note the last step 
"13. Now you are done and the bootloader is unlocked and YOU HAVE ROOT ACCESS. "

Then I adb shell & su at the shell prompt:

shell@yellowtail:/ $ su

and I get this:

CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: could not load library "libbinder.so" needed by "/system/bin/su"; caused by "libbinder.so" has u
nexpected e_machine: 3

I repeated all of the above again just to make sure I did it correctly. 
My questions: 
Do I (as the Dell Doc'n says) or do I not have root access?
If no how do I get it?
If yes, how do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

I rooted my *3730* using MyKitBatch from social-design-concepts on [XDADevs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2681783). It is just a root, not a ROM so it is model agnostic. It hasn't been updated in a year but it works with the 3730 and 3830.

If it doesn't work the OP/dev of mykit created this which they also claim has 3830 support, I have never tested it.

Comment: ok...thanks but I've got questions:
I went here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/intel-android-devices-root-temp-cwm-t2975096/post57543924#post57543924

It says to do this:
"make sure you have download the latest : UPDATE-SuperSU-vX.Xx.zip and place it on your internal or external_sd."


I'm confused. Are they saying to place the entire zip onto the device? or just the "Superuser.apk" w/in the .zip?

Comment: I believe that the script wants the entire ZIP but it wouldn't hurt to put both the zip and the apk.